# config nhibernate for oracle and sql in same application

Tags: nhibernate, configuration, web.config-transform

i need to create  switchable web.config file which can configure N Hibernate to work with either MS-SQL Server or Oracle

I'm having 2 configuration files  and one web.config files

sqlcongif.config
 oracleconfig.config

if i want only SQL config i need to point  to sqlconfigure.config in web.config
or else only oracle i need to point oracleconfig.config

tried with child config and other web options .

i found that similar problem when we are having connection strings in web config files 
is there any options we can do this ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be easily solved with a switch in code *(Oracle or SQL server)*, at the place where we ask for a `ISessionFactory`.

We just have to pass the **config name** and the **connection string key**:

```
public ISessionFactory BuildFactory(
   string configFileName
   string connectionStringKey)
{
    // full path to the config
    var fullfileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
                  , configFileName);
    var document = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(fullfileName);

    // NH configuration
    var config = new  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();

    // feeded with all the setting in our config
    using (var reader = document.CreateReader())
    {
        config.Configure(reader);
    }

    // read connection string from web.config
    // ADVANTAGE: it could be even encrypted
    var connectionStringFromWebConfig = ConfigurationManager
          .ConnectionStrings[connectionStringKey].ConnectionString;

    // use that web.config connection string
    config.SetProperty("connection.connection_string", connectionStringFromWebConfig);

    // create factory
    NHibernate.ISessionFactory factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
    return factory;
}
```

And then we can call it like

```
var factory = BuildFactory("config/sqlconfigure.config", "sqlServerConnection")
```